# Need to integrate Google Authentication in my web application

Tags: c#

I am having a web application in .net (3.5) and MySQL Server. I need to
add google authentication in my application in which, user is
authenticated at google with his username and password, and if
authenticated, i will be able to get email, firstname and lastname of
that google user.

Comment: This isnt a question. Its a statement.

Answer (score 2):

You can use OpenID to support multiple types of login, including Google auth.

http://bhaidar.net/post/2011/04/04/OpenID-Single-Sign-On-ASPNET-Web-Forms.aspx